# How to convert an SSL certificate in linux

Tags: linux, ssl, openssl, certificate

Is there a way how to convert certificates between cer/pem/crt/der/pfx/p12 in Linux? I have an SSL certificate in a .cer file and I need it to be .pem in order to use it.

How can I convert it?

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Converting certificates between cer/pem/crt/der/pfx/p12 can be done in Linux with the use of **OpenSSL** tool via the terminal.

These commands allow you to convert certificates and keys to different formats to make them compatible with specific types of servers or software.

**Convert a DER file (.crt .cer .der) to PEM**

> openssl x509 -inform der -in certificate.cer -out certificate.pem

**Convert a PEM file to DER**

> openssl x509 -outform der -in certificate.pem -out certificate.der

**Convert a PKCS#12 file (.pfx .p12) containing a private key and certificates to PEM**

> openssl pkcs12 -in keyStore.pfx -out keyStore.pem -nodes

You can add -nocerts to only output the private key or add -nokeys to only output the certificates.

**Convert a PEM certificate file and a private key to PKCS#12 (.pfx .p12)**

> openssl pkcs12 -export -out certificate.pfx -inkey privateKey.key -in certificate.crt -certfile CACert.crt

For more information see:

> http://www.sslshopper.com/article-most-common-openssl-commands.html
>
> https://support.ssl.com/index.php?/Knowledgebase/Article/View/19

Answer (score 2):

**Convert .crt to .p12**

openssl pkcs12 -export -out server.p12 -inkey server.key -in server.crt

Where server.key , is the server key . 
server.crt is cert file from CA or self sigh

Comment: Thanks for extending the list!