# converting apache2 self-signed certificate to p12 format

Tags: openssl, certificate

I'm trying create a certificate file that Android 4.3 will recognize in order to access a web site with a self-signed cert without having to click through a warning page. I think my current problem is getting the certificate into the correct format that Android will recognize.

First, I have read that "Android only understands user certificates in *.p12 file format." Is it correct to assume that the server.crt file on the server is the certificate that this is referring to? The first line in server.crt reads

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
```

I have been trying to follow the procedures given in the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16583428/how-to-convert-an-ssl-certificate-in-linux). The first thing I note is under:

```
Convert a DER file (.crt .cer .der) to PEM
```

Does this mean that all those extensions are always DER files? When I try to use the command that follows, I get this error:

```
$openssl x509 -inform der -in server.crt -out ~/server.pem
unable to load certificate 
140735083343132:error:0D0680A8:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_CHECK_TLEN:wrong tag:tasn_dec.c:1319:
140735083343132:error:0D07803A:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_ITEM_EX_D2I:nested asn1 error:tasn_dec.c:381:Type=X509
```

The second problem is in the examples I have found talk about how to get the certificate in p12 format.  There always seems to be some mention of a private key, but I don't think that is appropriate for exporting a self-signed certificate, is it?

For instance, to

```
Convert a PEM certificate file and a private key to PKCS#12 (.pfx .p12)
```

It gives the command:

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -out certificate.pfx -inkey privateKey.key -in certificate.crt -certfile CACert.crt
```

But I don't have a CACert.crt (because server.crt is self-signed?), the only .crt file I have is server.crt.  Also, as I need to convert crt and not pem  to p12, I wanted to try to combine the input part of the former command with the output part of the latter. But the former uses the "x509" command while the latter uses "pkcs12" so which one am I supposed to use?

Update:

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -inkey server.key -in server.crt -out ~/server.p12
```

Seems to work, and I am able to import the certificate into Android (it even claims it is installed in a toaste message), but afterwards it still does not show up in the user certificates list, and attempts to visit the website with the certificate still result in "The site's security certificate is not trusted!" message I have to click through.